# Should we use same bindings for loading and for retrieving data?

Tags: oop, architecture, software-design

For instance, in our application we can load data into DB from some messaging broker and, at the same time, retrieve this data from DB.

Should we use same bindings for loading and for retrieving? Or it's not necessary in common case and it'd be better to create separate bindings for loading and for retrieval?

Answer (score 0):

According to Command-query separation principle, you should not use the same binding for loading and retrieving data at the same time. In this way, any value-returning method (any query) can be called by any assertion without fear of modifying program state.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

Answer (score 0):

As usual it depends, without the details about your project it's hard to answer your question. Ask yourself are there any problems with the same binding in your project? How can you benefit from separate bindings? Think about all pros and cons and then make your decision. Just don't use a pattern or a technology because everyone is talking about it these days. All approaches have their pros and cons and developers tend to over engineer things a lot. Remember, a successfully project is the one which does the job, was finished within the budget and met the deadline not the one which has a lot of cool acronyms such as SQRS, DDD, TDD, etc. on its stack.